# Java Strings : Issue with Ascii values

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have `array of strings, String[] data` and it's 10 elements has value `P` and so `data[10]={java.lang.String@587}"P"`

When I do inspect on `data[10]`, i get `data[10].value[0] = 'P' 80`, am not sure what that `80` is referring too.

In my program, am trying to check

```
if (data[10] == "P") {
    lookUp = data[7] + "." + data[8]+ "." + "Old";
} else if (data[10] == "C") {
    lookUpCode = data[7] + "." + data[8] + "." + "Old";
} else {
    lookUpCode = data[7] + "." + data[8];
}
```

So challenge I have here is that even if `data[10]="P"` even then i hit last `else` and not first `if` loop, any suggestions?

Comment: `==` in Java compares the *reference values* the variables contain. Java is not C++ ;)

Comment: If `data` has 10 elements, then trying to access `data[10]` should result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Only indices 0 up to and including 9 are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare strings by value, not by reference:

```
if ("P".equals(data[10]))
```

Comment: ...Really?  Are you _sure_ that's what you want?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I was doing it wrong and so it was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In Java to compare strings you have to use the equals(String s) method. In your code:

```
data[10].equals("P")
```

This because strings are objects, and "==" compares the objects references.